# Setting sun.rmi.transport.tcp.maxConnectionThreads

Tags: java, tcp, rmi

I'm using Java RMI but I need to restrict the number of simultaneous connections to my server.

I know there are a few sun.rmi properties that define this like sun.rmi.transport.tcp.maxConnectionThreads

but I don't know how to change it since there doesn't seem to be a specific method or clas of properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a system property. You can change it via the command line, or via `System.setProperty(),` before you execute any RMI code.

Comment: When using, for example, `System.getProperties().put("sun.rmi.transport.tcp.maxConnectionThreads", "5")` it is important to store the number as a `String`, otherwise it will not work, because reading the system property is done with `Integer.getInteger` which wants a `String`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add a parameter to the program's run command, for example `-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.maxConnectionThreads=5`